# how to escape character in jython

Tags: websphere, jython

I am trying to put a property into Websphere console like **sso_1.sp.filter=request-url%=/api**

I tried a few commands similar to the below one. But I always ended up with different strings. I believe the issue is the % in the middle. How to escape it?

```
%PROFILE_PATH%\bin\wsadmin.bat -lang jython -c "AdminTask.configureInterceptor('[-interceptor com.ibm.ws.security.web.saml.ACSTrustAssociationInterceptor -customProperties["sso_1.sp.filter=request-url\%=/api"] ]')"
```

Comment: Tried %% ? I'm a little concerned about cmd.exe vs jython.

Comment: yes. Tried %% as escape % for % in cmd.exe. It didn't work.

Comment: escaping the inner quote marks was what it took to get this to work:
`wsadmin.bat -lang jython -conntype none -c "var=\"%%x/api\"; print var"`
prints  %x/api

Answer (score 0):

the working version.

```
wsadmin.bat -lang jython -c "AdminTask.configureInterceptor('[-interceptor com.ibm.ws.security.web
.saml.ACSTrustAssociationInterceptor -customProperties[\"sso_1.sp.filter=request-url%=/api\"] ]')"
```